# ATtiny85 - Sleep Mode & Interrupts

Tags: interrupts, sleep, attiny85

I am working with ATtiny85. I want to put my MCU in IDLE Sleep mode and after every five minutes, I want to write data into EEPROM. I am using Timer 0 overflow interrupt to count 5 mins. Counting will be done in ISR. I have a query here

1. Does CPU come out of IDLE Sleep mode when timmer overflow interrupt is generated?
   In the datasheet, they didn't give Timmer Overflow interrupt as a wake-up source.

```
void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);  
  set_eeprom_default(); // Initialize the EEPROM with default values
  configure_idle_mode(); // Configure idle sleep mode bits
  configure_interrupt_wakeup();
  timer_setup(); // Initialize timer and start timer
  EEPROM.get(Address, timer_count); // Get the value of timer counter
}

void loop() {
  if (timer_count < max_timer_count) {
    enable_sleep(); // Enable Sleep mode. MCU goes to sleep here
  }

  if (is_five_min == 1) { // Update EEPROM value after every 5 min
    update_eeprom();
    is_five_min = 0; // Reset the flag
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using an attiny85 or esp32?

Comment: I am using ATtiny85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, TIMER0 overflow is a wakeup from sleep. Relevant text in **Section 7.1.1**: "Idle mode enables the MCU to wake up from external triggered interrupts as well as internal ones *like the Timer Overflow*". Also see **Table 9-1** (Reset and Interrupt Vectors). It sounds like you've already declared the `TMR0_OVF_vect` ISR.

Additionally, `enable_sleep` does not put the AVR into the sleep mode, it only sets the `SE` bit in the **MCUCR** register. You have to call `sleep_cpu()` afterwards to actually put the microcontroller to sleep. Typically, the sequence would be:

```
sleep_enable();  // Set SE bit
sei();           // Enable interrupts
sleep_cpu();     // Go to sleep
sleep_disable(); // Clear SE bit
```

See the description of this in the [avr-libc documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__sleep.html).

Comment: Thank you awjlogan